# How can I make my for loop run through every number in my list test_cases?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, user-defined-functions

I am having trouble trying to run my code 5 times to display the factors of the following numbers in my list labelled test_cases. How can I do it using the most simplest python functions without running into an error?

```
def generate_factors(y):
    for i in range(1, y + 1): 
        if y % i == 0:
            print(i, end=' ')

test_cases = [20, 31, 140, 222, 517]

for one_tc in test_cases:
    print(f'The factors are: ')
    generate_factors(test_cases)
```

Comment: I _think_ rather than `generate_factors(test_cases)` you want to have `generate_factors(one_tc)`.

Comment: You are passing a list, `test_cases` to `generate_factors`

Comment: @alfinkel24 how silly of me! thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're specifying the list `test_cases` as an input to `generate_factors`, but it should be the integer `one_tc`. Try this instead:

```
def generate_factors(y):
    for i in range(1, y + 1): 
        if y % i == 0:
            print(i, end=' ')

test_cases = [20, 31, 140, 222, 517]

for one_tc in test_cases:
    print(f'The factors are: ')
    generate_factors(one_tc)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def generate_factors(y):
    for i in range(1, y + 1): 
        if y % i == 0:
            print(i, end='\n')
    
    

test_cases = [20, 31, 140, 222, 517]

for one_tc in test_cases:
    print(f'The factors of: ',one_tc)
    generate_factors(one_tc)
```

Comment: Your welcome. Upvote this answer if you feel useful.

Comment: can I also ask another thing related to this question? so the results for 20 is 1, 2, 4, 5, 10, 20. how do i remove the number 1 and 20 from this?

Comment: This should probably be a new question.